# 3D block model for Minecraft works as item but becomes a null block when places (Minecraft Modding 1.16.5)

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I have a block that is a 3d model that's going to be similar to a skull. It renders the model as a item but when I place it it becomes a null block.

[image: the item works as a model and in my inventory but doesn't seem to work as a block.]

Originally it was going to be a armor piece but I can't find anything that teaches me how to make 3d armor. So now Its a wearable block. I didn't implent the wearable feature yet. So any help to make the block like a skull is needed.

Here is my block model code:

```
{
"credit": "Made with Blockbench",
"parent": "beeutil:block/bee_helmet",
"ambientocclusion": false,
"texture_size": [32, 32],
"textures": {
    "0": "beeutil:block/bee_helmet",
    "particle": "beeutil:block/bee_helmet"
},
"elements": [
    {
        "from": [3, 0, 3],
        "to": [13, 9, 13],
        "faces": {
            "north": {"uv": [5, 0, 10, 4.5], "texture": "#0"},
            "east": {"uv": [5, 4.5, 10, 9], "texture": "#0"},
            "south": {"uv": [5, 9, 10, 13.5], "texture": "#0"},
            "west": {"uv": [0, 10, 5, 14.5], "texture": "#0"},
            "up": {"uv": [5, 5, 0, 0], "texture": "#0"},
            "down": {"uv": [5, 5, 0, 10], "texture": "#0"}
        }
    },
    {
        "from": [3, 9, 5],
        "to": [4, 12, 6],
        "faces": {
            "north": {"uv": [10, 2, 10.5, 3.5], "texture": "#0"},
            "east": {"uv": [10, 3.5, 10.5, 5], "texture": "#0"},
            "south": {"uv": [10, 5, 10.5, 6.5], "texture": "#0"},
            "west": {"uv": [10, 6.5, 10.5, 8], "texture": "#0"},
            "up": {"uv": [11.5, 2.5, 11, 2], "texture": "#0"},
            "down": {"uv": [11.5, 2.5, 11, 3], "texture": "#0"}
        }
    },
    {
        "from": [3, 11, 6],
        "to": [4, 13, 7],
        "faces": {
            "north": {"uv": [10.5, 5, 11, 6], "texture": "#0"},
            "east": {"uv": [10.5, 6, 11, 7], "texture": "#0"},
            "south": {"uv": [10.5, 7, 11, 8], "texture": "#0"},
            "west": {"uv": [10.5, 8, 11, 9], "texture": "#0"},
            "up": {"uv": [11.5, 3.5, 11, 3], "texture": "#0"},
            "down": {"uv": [11.5, 3.5, 11, 4], "texture": "#0"}
        }
    },
    {
        "from": [3, 11, 11],
        "to": [4, 13, 13],
        "faces": {
            "north": {"uv": [10.5, 9, 11, 10], "texture": "#0"},
            "east": {"uv": [10, 0, 11, 1], "texture": "#0"},
            "south": {"uv": [10.5, 10, 11, 11], "texture": "#0"},
            "west": {"uv": [10, 1, 11, 2], "texture": "#0"},
            "up": {"uv": [11.5, 1, 11, 0], "texture": "#0"},
            "down": {"uv": [11.5, 1, 11, 2], "texture": "#0"}
        }
    },
    {
        "from": [3, 9, 10],
        "to": [4, 12, 11],
        "faces": {
            "north": {"uv": [10, 8, 10.5, 9.5], "texture": "#0"},
            "east": {"uv": [10, 9.5, 10.5, 11], "texture": "#0"},
            "south": {"uv": [10.5, 2, 11, 3.5], "texture": "#0"},
            "west": {"uv": [10.5, 3.5, 11, 5], "texture": "#0"},
            "up": {"uv": [11.5, 4.5, 11, 4], "texture": "#0"},
            "down": {"uv": [11.5, 4.5, 11, 5], "texture": "#0"}
        }
    }
],
"display": {
    "thirdperson_righthand": {
        "rotation": [0, -90, -90],
        "scale": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    },
    "thirdperson_lefthand": {
        "rotation": [90, 90, 0],
        "scale": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    },
    "firstperson_righthand": {
        "rotation": [0, -90, 0],
        "translation": [0, 3, 0],
        "scale": [0.8, 0.8, 0.8]
    },
    "firstperson_lefthand": {
        "rotation": [0, 90, 0]
    },
    "ground": {
        "translation": [0, 4.75, 0]
    },
    "gui": {
        "rotation": [0, 90, 0],
        "translation": [0, 2.5, 0]
    },
    "head": {
        "rotation": [0, -90, 0],
        "translation": [-0.25, 5.5, 0],
        "scale": [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
    },
    "fixed": {
        "rotation": [0, -90, 0],
        "translation": [0, 4, 0]
    }
}
```

}

Here is my blockstates code:

```
  {
    "varients": {
      "": { "model":  "beeutil:block/bee_helmet"}
    }
  }
```

Here is my model item code:

```
{
  "parent": "beeutil:block/bee_helmet"
}
```

Comment: If anyone still is viewing this. I have not found any answer yet. Though still wanted. Thanks!